# Titanium: Different execution contexts are not multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, titanium, context-switch

I am trying to use titanium execution contexts to produce parallel code execution between the main application context and others. I am using CreateWindow with a url property refers to a .js file inside "lib" folder. But by logging the execution on both iOS and Android devices it seems that different contexts are executed on the app main thread, no parallelism here.

My new context trigger inside my Alloy controller:

```
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  title: 'New Window',
  url: 'thread.js',
  backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

win2.open();
Ti.API.log('after open');
```

My thread.js contents:

```
Ti.API.log("this is the new context");
Ti.App.fireEvent("go" , {});
while(true)
{
    Ti.API.log('second context');
}
```

This while loop apparently blocks the main context (my Alloy controller) waiting it to exit.

Any suggestions of how can I execute some code (mainly heavy sqlite db access) in background so that the UI be responsive? (Web workers are not a choice for me).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve the wanted behaviour with a `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` method.

setInterval()[[source]](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136893/how-to-call-a-function-in-specific-time-interval-when-the-app-is-in-background):

```
function myFunc() {
    //your code
}
//set the interval
setInterval(myFunc,2000) //this will run the function for every 2 sec.
```

Another suggested method would be to fire a custom event when you need the background behavior since it is processed in its own thread. This is also suggested in the [official documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Coding_Strategies).

Comment: I don't want timer behavior, I want a continuous background context. The while loop in my code is just a way to know whether the 2 contexts are run in parallel. setTimeout() runs the desired function on the same thread.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the setTimeout() part to avoid people from trying it and added the source for the event mechanism. I am sorry I could not help you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, titanium is single threaded, because JavaScript is single threaded. You can get parallel execution with native modules, but you'll have to code that yourself for each platform.

Another option is to use web workers, but I consider that to be a hack.